# Recode catagorical variable as integers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've asked this question for R but am now trying to do it in pandas. I'm trying to use pandas to recode a categorical variable to integers. Given:

```
group
 005j         
 005j         
 0k16         
 0fff       
 0fff
```

I'd like to get a series of increasing integers representing the same grouping:

```
group   intCode
 005j      1   
 005j      1   
 0k16      2   
 0fff      3 
 0fff      3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just providing an updated version of @herrfz's answer. `Categorical.from_array` and `labels` have been deprecated.

```
df['intCode'] = pd.Categorical(df.group).codes
```

worked for me running Python 3.6.9

Answer (score 8):

```
In [10]: df['intCode'] = pd.Categorical.from_array(df.group).labels

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
  group  intCode
0  005j        0
1  005j        0
2  0k16        2
3  0fff        1
4  0fff        1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get unique values

```
>>> df = pd.read_clipboard()
>>> groups = df['group'].unique()
```

Index them

```
>>> groups = pd.DataFrame(groups, columns=['group']).reset_index()
```

And merge back (adding 1 to start from 1 instead of 0):

```
>>> groups['index'] += 1
>>> df.merge(groups)
  group  index
0  005j      1
1  005j      1
2  0k16      2
3  0fff      3
4  0fff      3

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```